# Efficient full text search in PostgreSQL, sorting on another column

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search, query-optimization, postgresql-13, postgresql-14

**In PostgreSQL, how can one efficiently do a full text search on one column, sorting on another column?**

Say I have a table `tbl` with columns `a`, `b`, `c`, ... and many (> a million) rows. I want to do a full text search on column `a` and sort the results by some other column.

So I create a tsvector `va` from column `a`,

```
ALTER TABLE tbl
ADD COLUMN va tsvector GENERATED ALWAYS AS (to_tsvector('english', a)) STORED;
```

create an index `iva` for that,

```
CREATE INDEX iva ON tbl USING GIN (va);
```

and an index `ib` for column `b`,

```
CREATE INDEX ib ON tbl (b);
```

Then I query like

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE va @@ to_tsquery('english', 'test') ORDER BY b LIMIT 100
```

Now the obvious execution strategy for Postgres would be:

1. for frequent words to do an Index Scan using `ib`, filtering for `va @@ 'test'::tsquery`, and stopping after 100 matches,
2. while for rare words to do a (Bitmap) Index Scan using `iva` with condition
   `va @@ 'test'::tsquery`, and then to sort on `b` manually

However, Postgres' query planner seems not to take word frequency into account:

- With a low `LIMIT` (e.g. `100`) it always uses strategy 1 (as I checked with `EXPLAIN`), and in my case takes over a minute for rare (or not occurring) words. However, if I trick it into using strategy 2 by setting a large (or no) `LIMIT`, it returns in a millisecond!
- The other way round, with a larger `LIMIT` (e.g. `200`) it always uses strategy 2 which works well for rare words but is very slow for frequent words

***So how do I get Postgres to use a good query plan in every case?***

Since there seems currently no way to let Postgres to choose the right plan automatically,

- how do I get the number of rows containing a specific lexeme so I can decide on the best strategy?

  (`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl WHERE va @@ to_tsquery('english', 'test')` is horribly slow (~ 1 second for lexemes occurring in 10000 rows), and `ts_stat` seems also not to help, apart from building my own word frequency list)
- how do I then tell Postgres to use this strategy?

---

**Here a concrete example**

I have a table `items` with 1.5 million rows, with a tsvector column `v3` on which I do the text search, and a column `rating` on which I sort. In this case I determined the query planner always chooses strategy 1 if the LIMIT is 135 or less, else strategy 2

Here the EXPLAIN ANALYZE for the rare word 'aberdeen' (occurring in 132 rows) with LIMIT 135:

```
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) SELECT nm FROM items WHERE v3 @@ to_tsquery('english', 'aberdeen')
  ORDER BY rating DESC NULLS LAST LIMIT 135

Limit  (cost=0.43..26412.78 rows=135 width=28) (actual time=5915.455..499917.390 rows=132 loops=1)
  Buffers: shared hit=4444267 read=2219412
  I/O Timings: read=485517.381
  ->  Index Scan using ir on items  (cost=0.43..1429202.13 rows=7305 width=28) (actual time=5915.453..499917.242 rows=132 loops=1)
        Filter: (v3 @@ '''aberdeen'''::tsquery)"
        Rows Removed by Filter: 1460845
        Buffers: shared hit=4444267 read=2219412
        I/O Timings: read=485517.381
Planning:
  Buffers: shared hit=253
Planning Time: 1.270 ms
Execution Time: 499919.196 ms
```

and with LIMIT 136:

```
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) SELECT nm FROM items WHERE v3 @@ to_tsquery('english', 'aberdeen')
  ORDER BY rating DESC NULLS LAST LIMIT 136

Limit  (cost=26245.53..26245.87 rows=136 width=28) (actual time=29.870..29.889 rows=132 loops=1)
  Buffers: shared hit=57 read=83
  I/O Timings: read=29.085
  ->  Sort  (cost=26245.53..26263.79 rows=7305 width=28) (actual time=29.868..29.876 rows=132 loops=1)
        Sort Key: rating DESC NULLS LAST
        Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 34kB
        Buffers: shared hit=57 read=83
        I/O Timings: read=29.085
        ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on items  (cost=88.61..25950.14 rows=7305 width=28) (actual time=1.361..29.792 rows=132 loops=1)
              Recheck Cond: (v3 @@ '''aberdeen'''::tsquery)"
              Heap Blocks: exact=132
              Buffers: shared hit=54 read=83
              I/O Timings: read=29.085
              ->  Bitmap Index Scan on iv3  (cost=0.00..86.79 rows=7305 width=0) (actual time=1.345..1.345 rows=132 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: (v3 @@ '''aberdeen'''::tsquery)"
                    Buffers: shared hit=3 read=2
                    I/O Timings: read=1.299
Planning:
  Buffers: shared hit=253
Planning Time: 1.296 ms
Execution Time: 29.932 ms
```

and here for the frequent word 'game' (occurring in 240464 rows) with LIMIT 135:

```
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) SELECT nm FROM items WHERE v3 @@ to_tsquery('english', 'game')
  ORDER BY rating DESC NULLS LAST LIMIT 135

Limit  (cost=0.43..26412.78 rows=135 width=28) (actual time=3.240..542.252 rows=135 loops=1)
  Buffers: shared hit=2876 read=1930
  I/O Timings: read=529.523
  ->  Index Scan using ir on items  (cost=0.43..1429202.13 rows=7305 width=28) (actual time=3.239..542.216 rows=135 loops=1)
        Filter: (v3 @@ '''game'''::tsquery)
        Rows Removed by Filter: 867
        Buffers: shared hit=2876 read=1930
        I/O Timings: read=529.523
Planning:
  Buffers: shared hit=208 read=45
  I/O Timings: read=15.626
Planning Time: 25.174 ms
Execution Time: 542.306 ms
```

and with LIMIT 136:

```
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) SELECT nm FROM items WHERE v3 @@ to_tsquery('english', 'game')
  ORDER BY rating DESC NULLS LAST LIMIT 136
  
Limit  (cost=26245.53..26245.87 rows=136 width=28) (actual time=69419.656..69419.675 rows=136 loops=1)
  Buffers: shared hit=1757820 read=457619
  I/O Timings: read=65246.893
  ->  Sort  (cost=26245.53..26263.79 rows=7305 width=28) (actual time=69419.654..69419.662 rows=136 loops=1)
        Sort Key: rating DESC NULLS LAST
        Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 41kB
        Buffers: shared hit=1757820 read=457619
        I/O Timings: read=65246.893
        ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on items  (cost=88.61..25950.14 rows=7305 width=28) (actual time=110.959..69326.343 rows=240464 loops=1)
              Recheck Cond: (v3 @@ '''game'''::tsquery)
              Rows Removed by Index Recheck: 394527
              Heap Blocks: exact=49894 lossy=132284
              Buffers: shared hit=1757817 read=457619
              I/O Timings: read=65246.893
              ->  Bitmap Index Scan on iv3  (cost=0.00..86.79 rows=7305 width=0) (actual time=100.537..100.538 rows=240464 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: (v3 @@ '''game'''::tsquery)
                    Buffers: shared hit=1 read=60
                    I/O Timings: read=26.870
Planning:
  Buffers: shared hit=253
Planning Time: 1.195 ms
Execution Time: 69420.399 ms
```

Comment: What version?  The planner is not static.

Comment: Postgres 13, what do you mean with "not static"?

Comment: not static = gets improved from version to version.

Comment: It seems to do a good job to me.  Can you show us concrete EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) from concrete cases, and replace '> a million', 'rare', and 'frequent' with quantitative values?  Turn on track_io_timing first if possible.

Comment: @jjanes I have now given a concrete example as you asked for

Answer (score 6):

This is not easy to solve: full text search requires a GIN index, but a GIN index cannot support `ORDER BY`. Also, if you have a B-tree index for `ORDER BY` and a GIN index for the full text search, these can be combined using a bitmap index scan, but a bitmap index scan cannot support `ORDER BY` either.

I see a certain possibility if you create your own “stop word” list that contains all the frequent words in your data (in addition to the normal English stop words). Then you can define a text search dictionary that uses that stop word file and a text search configuration `english_rare` using that dictionary.

Then you could create your full text index using that configuration and query in two steps like this:

1. look for rare words:

   ```
   SELECT *
   FROM (SELECT *
         FROM tbl
         WHERE va @@ to_tsquery('english_rare', 'test')
         OFFSET 0) AS q
   ORDER BY b LIMIT 100;
   ```

   The subquery with `OFFSET 0` will keep the optimizer from scanning the index on `b`.

   For rare words, this will return the correct result quickly.  For frequent words, this will return nothing, since `to_tsquery` will return an empty result.  To distinguish between a miss because the word does not occur and a miss because the word is frequent, watch for the following notice:

   ```
   NOTICE:  text-search query contains only stop words or doesn't contain lexemes, ignored
   ```
2. look for frequent words (if the first query gave you the notice):

   ```
   SELECT *
   FROM (SELECT *
         FROM tbl
         ORDER BY b) AS q
   WHERE va @@ to_tsquery('english', 'test')
   LIMIT 100;
   ```

   Note that we use the normal English configuration here. This will always scan the index on `b` and will be reasonably fast for frequent search terms.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It seems far better than my first idea (launch two concurrent queries and kill the one that takes time as soon as the other answers...). My concern now is that the "frequent words" dictionary may be quite big depending on the thresold i choose for frequent. I do my tests and come back to you

Comment: Yes, composing that file is the Achilles' heel of my idea.

Comment: Maybe another point of attention is that for the first query, if searching for multiple words, OR operator is mandatory. It raises some interesting questions :).

Comment: A search string with several words is interpreted as "and", and that would be no problem. But if the search string contains an `|`, that would be a problem for my strategy. Either forbid that, or split the search string and treat each element separately.

Comment: @Vincent, I have now reported my experience

Answer (score 3):

*Solution for my scenario, which I think will work well for many real-world cases:*

**Let Postgres use the "rare-word strategy" (2. in the question) always or mostly.** The reason is that there always should be the possibility for a user to sort by relevance (e.g. using `ts_rank`), in which case the other strategy cannot be used, so one has to make sure that the "rare-word strategy" is fast enough for all searches anyway.

**To force Postgres to use this strategy one can use a subquery**, as Laurenz Albe has pointed out:

```
SELECT * FROM 
    (SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE va @@ to_tsquery('english', 'test') OFFSET 0) AS q
ORDER BY b LIMIT 100;
```

Alternatively one can simply set `LIMIT` sufficiently high (while only fetching as many results as needed).

I could **achieve sufficient performance** (nearly all queries take < 1 second) by

- doing each search first against a smaller `ts_vector` containing the most relevant parts of each document (e.g. title and summary), and checking the full document only if this first query yields not enough results.
- specially treating words occurring *very* frequently, e.g. only allowing them in AND-combination with other words (adding them to the stop words is problematic since those are not sensibly treated when occurring in phrases for example)
- increasing RAM and increasing `shared_buffers` so the whole table can be cached (8.5 GB for me currently)

For **cases where these optimizations are not enough**, to achieve better performance for *all* queries (i.e. also those sorting by relevance, which are the hardest), I think one would have to use a more sophisticated text search index instead of GIN. There is the [RUM index extension](https://github.com/postgrespro/rum) which looks promising, but I haven't tried it yet.

---

**PS**: Contrary to my observation in the question I have now found that under certain circumstances the planner *does* take word frequency into account and makes decisions in the right direction:

For rare words the borderline `LIMIT` above which it chooses the "rare-word strategy" is lower than for frequent words, and in a certain range this choice seems very good. However this is in no way reliable and sometimes the choice is very wrong, e.g. for low `LIMIT`s it chooses the "frequent-word strategy" also for very rare or non-occurring words which leads to awful slowness.

It appears to depend on many factors and seems not predictable.